# Foreach DataGridViewRow procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So, after many tryings (and changing the source idea of project) I made some code which works well if one row is selected (i.e. some cells of one single row).
But, I want to repeat the same for multiple rows ( if any cell selected) - except for the first and last row (i.e. rowIndex 0 and newRow). Things become too complicated. Could somebody help?

```
int r = dgvC.CurrentRow.Index;
var selCells = dgvC.SelectedCells;
var hColumn = (from DataGridViewCell c in selCells;
               orderby c.ColumnIndex descending select c).FirstOrDefault();

List<DataGridViewCell> q = new List<DataGridViewCell> { };
foreach (DataGridViewCell p in dgvC.CurrentRow.Cells)
{
    if (p.ColumnIndex > hColumn.ColumnIndex)
    {
        q.Add(p);
    }
}

foreach (DataGridViewCell v in dgvN.Rows[r].Cells)
{
    if (v.ColumnIndex > 0)
    {
        q.Add(v);
    }
}

List<string> a = new List<string> { };
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells)
{
    a.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
    a.Reverse();
}

List<string> result = (from ignored in Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                       from item in a select item).Take(q.Count).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
{
    q.ElementAt(i).Value = result.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Comment: No, but separate parts by the Space.

Comment: Never seen that convention...I don't like it.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the values in the selected cells in each row? What if the selection is not a rectangle (you can add/remove individual cells from the selection list with Ctrl+Left Click)?

Comment: yes, whatever i did in the presented row - I need to do for each other, sequentially. I will prevent user somehow to make unRectangle selection.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this code at all. You have two DataGridViews (dgvC and dgvN) which presumably have the same number of rows (since r is an index into dgvC but is used against dgvN, also). hColumn is the rightmost selected cell. So you take the values in your selected cells from right to left and write those values into every cell to the right of hColumn in dgvC and continue doing the same in dgvN starting in column 1?

Comment: no parens and no indent make code confusing...

Comment: Dominic, it seems, you have no trouble understanding this code.

Comment: Confusing code which have max 4 lines in each of 6 parts ? parens are not needed for executing code. Maybe I should drow some flowers and birds.

Comment: @Bonaca Or perhaps when you come to a site for help, you make it as easy as possible to help you. You can keep the flowers and birds.

Comment: I took care of those troublesome braces and indentations for you. I had 3 extra minutes in my day to spare. I did, however, down-vote you for the effort. I'm not an anonymous down-voter. =)

Comment: You spend more then 3 minutes engaging in irrelevant matters (parens or no parens). AnyWay - ThankYou.

Comment: @Bonaca Yes, if spending 3 minutes makes my code easier to read for others, I'll do that. I learned that in my first programming course. Happy to help (the other ppl trying to read that mess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code needs a complete rewrite. I'm assuming the following about your intentions, sort of confirmed in the discussion above.

You start with two DGVs, which look like this:

```
dgvC                         dgvN
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+ 
|  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  | |  N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6  |
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+
|  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  | |  v20 v21 v22 v23 v24 v25 |
|  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 | |  v26 v27 v28 v29 v30 v31 |
|  v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 | |  v32 v33 v34 v35 v36 v37 |
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+
```

If the user selects C2 and C3 of row 2 in dgvC and runs your code, you want it to modify your tables like this:

```
dgvC                         dgvN
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+ 
|  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  | |  N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6  |
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+
|  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  | |  v20 v21 v22 v23 v24 v25 |
|  v7  v8  v9  v9  v8  v9  | |  v26 v8  v9  v8  v9  v8  |
|  v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 | |  v32 v33 v34 v35 v36 v37 |
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+
```

But, if you rectangle-select C2, C3, and C4 in rows 2 and 3, you want it to look like this:

```
dgvC                         dgvN
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+ 
|  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  | |  N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  N6  |
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+
|  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  | |  v20 v21 v22 v23 v24 v25 |
|  v7  v8  v9  v10 v10 v9  | |  v26 v8  v10 v9  v8  v10 |
|  v13 v14 v15 v16 v16 v15 | |  v32 v14 v16 v15 v14 v16 |
+--------------------------+ +--------------------------+
```

Am I correct so far?

If so, I would write the code like this:

```
int loRow = dgvC.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.RowIndex).Min();
int hiRow = dgvC.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.RowIndex).Max();

int loCol = dgvC.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.ColumnIndex).Min();
int hiCol = dgvC.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.ColumnIndex).Max();

for (int i = loRow; i <= hiRow; i++)
{
    // start copying from the rightmost selected cell in the current row
    int curCopyCol = hiCol;

    // now copy to dgvC, starting with hiCol + 1
    for (int j = hiCol + 1; j < dgvC.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dgvC.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = dgvC.Rows[i].Cells[curCopyCol--].Value;

        if (curCopyCol < loCol)
            curCopyCol = hiCol;
    }

    // finally, continue copying in dgvN, starting from the second cell
    for (int j = 1; j < dgvN.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dgvN.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = dgvC.Rows[i].Cells[curCopyCol--].Value;

        if (curCopyCol < loCol)
            curCopyCol = hiCol;
    }
}
```

This code has been tested in VS2010 targeting .NET 3.5.

**Edited** to fix and expand on the comments.

Comment: Dominic, it works. Congratulations for your goodNervesAndIntention.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try hooking into the datagrid view's row selected / cell selected events to keep track of what what row is selected?  This way, you can inspect the row that raised the event and determine whether to keep or remove it from an internal collection?  You can keep an internal collection of row objects or just indexes of rows that have been selected and work from that, instead of trying to build the list like your current code.

Comment: Internal collection instead list? The list is also internal, isn't it?

Comment: An internal list as a property of the viewmodel (or in this case, maybe form).